# Does Google Photos allow for "Hidden" albums or photos?

Tags: photos, google, google-photos

I have not found anywhere in Google Photos to "**hide**" and album, collection, or specific photo from view under any given context. *Is there a setting or workaround that will allow a user to select specific photos or albums from being in the main view when viewing photos in either the album view or timeline view?*

**Use case**: If one backs up every photo taken to Google Photos, it would be helpful to have "hidden" folders or photos that are only visible when selecting to view those photos or collections/albums, or various contextual "profiles" to view photos as, such as "Personal," "Business," or "Show All." That way, depending on the context of why the user is viewing the photos, one could see all photos that apply to that given context.

There was a lot of emphasis on "contextual learning" at Google I/O 2015, and this is one obvious way that it would seem Google Photos would work under that philosophy, so it may be that I just haven't found the setting yet.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen no indication anywhere, from every setting within the site or app to deep searches, that indicates any such feature exists. The last mention of it I see dates back to Picasa. It seems the feature died there.

I personally have entirely separate Google accounts for different needs, and I keep my photos in those locations that don't belong in my general collection. Not optimal, but the only solution I've found.

Answer (score 0):

2 options using the android app X-plore File Manager (amazing file manager)

1. You have to put the files in a zip file

Select everything you want hidden and tap and hold > pop up menu > "create zip"
You can still browse what is in the zip like its a folder in X-plore File Manager
You can then add new photos or video to the zip by simply copying to the zip

2. Make the folder your media is in "Hidden"

   - The names of videos might show up but the will not be playable

Add a dot to your folder name. example "Media" become ".Media"
Add a text file name ".nomedia" (no extension)
In X-plore File Manager top right click the three dots > Configuration > Show Hidden Files

Answer (score 0):

No, you could however use a Photo Vault app from the Play Store to hide images, using a password of your choice.